# Java send javascript object to nodejs

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js, socket.io

I am currently developping an Android app in java, and I have to send a javascript object for the node server to interpret it.

Javascript code:

```
    socket.emit('mousemove', { 'x': x, //int
     'y': y, // int
     'drawing': drawing, //boolean
     'id': id //int
});
```

I didn't try anything relevant since I was unable to include a boolean in an int[] array

How could I achieve that ?

PS: Someone told me about GSON, is it the right use ? Then, how to use it ?

Comment: @Samuel I tried passing an array, but I didn't test, because `drawing` variable is a boolean and others are integers.

Comment: "app in java" is a bit too vague. If it is a web application, you might do it with javascript code on the front-end or with Java code on the back-end, two entirely different problem domains with different solutions and technologies.

Comment: @Gimby It's an android app, which is a "port" of a web app.

Comment: Please also post what you did or tried, and what worked or not. Also, state that it's an Android app. Editing questions is encouraged compared to writing comments.

Comment: @AndreiTudorDiaconu Edited.

Comment: @FliiFe android is not really Java, it just uses an older version of the Java language. I would tag your question as an android question then to attract the proper crowd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnally I use JSON Java. Here's an exemple : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JSON/0100__JSON_Java.htm